# Is it true that only UTXOs can be used as Transaction Inputs?

Tags: transactions, utxo

I was reading this [GitHub](https://github.com/decentralisedkev/DecentralisedBookRepo/blob/master/decentralised-technology/terminology/deep-dive-utxos.md) book on Bitcoin

They state that "True or False: Only UTXOs can be used as inputs to transactions."

Is the answer, True because you can only spend what you have.

Or False, you can out a spent output in the transaction as input, but the network or the miner will reject it.

Comment: If everyone rejects your transaction, can you call that spending?

Comment: @alcio no, you can still use it for an input though right? There's nothing stopping you

Comment: In a technical sense, yes, you are not limited to the UTXO set for inputs, but in a practical sense, you are if you want your transaction to confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question makes no sense.

Of course you can make an *invalid* transaction that doesn't spend an unspent output. If you're fine with calling invalid things transactions, I could just take a piece of random data and call it a transaction.

A **valid** transaction can only spend unspent outputs.

Comment: Thank you, I think I was getting confused. Your concise answer cleared things up for me.